# SELECT Newest date based on Week and Year criteria

Tags: ms-access

I think i have a simple problem, i just cant figure it out. I have a table with ID, Date and Value
I want to select the NEWEST value based on criteria of week and year. Meaning i only have the year and week to find the newest value.

if you do the following
`SELECT TOP 1 Value from tbl WHERE year(Date)<=year and format(date,"WW")<= weeknumber`
you get a problem. because if the year is 2020 and the week is 30. then if there is a value from the 31/12/2019 it wont return it because `format(date,"WW")` is greater than the week.

Example: dateformat=dd/mm/yyyy

```
ID      Date     Value
1   15/01/2019    15 
2   31/12/2019    18
3   15/04/2020    19
```

if the week is 5 and the year is 2020
the result of the sql should be 18 since that is the newest value before the week and year. But the query i wrote above returns 15, which makes sence because of the week of 31/12/2019>5 and therefore wont be returned.

But how do i do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this probably is ISO 8601 week numbering, the year is not the calendar year but the *ISO 8601 year*, which native VBA knows nothing about, thus a custom function is needed:

```vb
' First day of the week.
WeekStart = DateYearWeek(5, 2020, vbMonday)
' WeekStart -> 2020-01-27
```

The function is not that convoluted:

```vb
' Returns the date of Monday for the ISO 8601 week of IsoYear and Week.
' Optionally, returns the date of any other weekday of that week.
'
' 2017-05-03. Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function DateYearWeek( _
    ByVal IsoWeek As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal IsoYear As Integer, _
    Optional ByVal DayOfWeek As VbDayOfWeek = VbDayOfWeek.vbMonday) _
    As Date

    Dim WeekDate    As Date
    Dim ResultDate  As Date

    If IsoYear = 0 Then
        IsoYear = Year(Date)
    End If

    ' Validate parameters.
    If Not IsWeekday(DayOfWeek) Then
        ' Don't accept invalid values for DayOfWeek.
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
        Exit Function
    End If
    If Not IsWeek(IsoWeek, IsoYear) Then
        ' A valid week number must be passed.
        Err.Raise DtError.dtInvalidProcedureCallOrArgument
        Exit Function
    End If

    WeekDate = DateAdd(IntervalSetting(dtWeek), IsoWeek - 1, DateFirstWeekYear(IsoYear))
    ResultDate = DateThisWeekPrimo(WeekDate, DayOfWeek)

    DateYearWeek = ResultDate

End Function
```

but - as you can see - it calls some helper functions, which again call other functions, which will be too much to post here.

I can upload it somewhere, if you feel this will provide a solution for you.

There is no simple work-around. On the other hand, once held in a module, the code is simple to implement - as you can see.